# Convert Json in DART -> the argument type 'dynamic' can´t be assignet to the parameter type Iteerable<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

I generated a json in dart class. So I'm getting an error message that I can't resolve. If anyone can help me I'd appreciate it!

**empresas = List.from(json['empresas']).map((e)=>Empresas.fromJson(e)).toList();**

Error -> the argument type 'dynamic' can´t be assignet to the parameter type Iterable

Json:

```
{
  "authenticated": true,
  "expiration": "07/07/2022 13:01:27",
  "message": "Login Válido",
  "typeToken": "Bearer",
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJFbWFpbCI6InRlc3RlQHNvdW1laS5hcHAuYnIiLCJVc3VhcmlvIjoiTWFudWVsYSBPcmxhbmRvIERpYXMiLCJTaXR1YWNhbyI6IkEiLCJleHAiOjE2NTcyMDk2ODcsImlzcyI6IkFsZ3VtSXNzdWVyIiwiYXVkIjoiQWxndW1hQXVkaWVuY2UifQ.c7sO8Hlrx17uX6x36otenOZDNxdoSBZbWBDbs7YA4_Q",
  "refreshToken": "xViQi5nj2fqgaT0j2sk/CriUs8zFtLHiLgPN8ARMmktVzHPRX6nKeDbTuPi3/p4B5PqewOCnFC7ZOPoXpcGyEEhkkqzuQYOJxk8vr3dv2BikdK01mrixqRkfbXaxCoXBuzTWzp4fywLO9uFhfWKGRl6/f6MZl6OXs/1Eg0ijEJJqngU+EC6RsApsWPjUlnPsqTG8ynLU6XbHmea+Rf5MO8qCwPVtekRq8ppIYpHAAtoPrhE2R3N7dAqkH++2UNxG1+iUHTdZd24qOGrOa9nmv5SnEEUd7x5gkMhG+n9ChQvRZym/WSv0JJr2P/xrwNWaY/oNPCfAMMu7EnFF1CLsJCgj8ZjTqo1gjpUYEOTliIs=",
  "contaContrato": 10000,
  "situacaoContrato": "A",
  "planoContratado": 0,
  "empresas": [
    {
      "contaEmpresa": 10000,
      "selecionada": 1,
      "razaoSocial": "Manuela e Jose Modas ME - 09.473.441/0001-85",
      "fantasia": "Basic Store",
      "identificador": "",
      "cpfcnpj": "09.473.441/0001-85",
      "apiToken": "d73cef62-ee28-40ec-86dd-08ba97af1a21"
    }
}
```

Class Dart:

```
class AutoGenerate {

  AutoGenerate({
    required this.authenticated,
    required this.expiration,
    required this.message,
    required this.typeToken,
    required this.token,
    required this.refreshToken,
    required this.contaContrato,
    required this.situacaoContrato,
    required this.planoContratado,
    required this.empresas,
  });
  late final bool authenticated;
  late final String expiration;
  late final String message;
  late final String typeToken;
  late final String token;
  late final String refreshToken;
  late final int contaContrato;
  late final String situacaoContrato;
  late final int planoContratado;
  late final List<Empresas> empresas;
  
  AutoGenerate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    authenticated = json['authenticated'];
    expiration = json['expiration'];
    message = json['message'];
    typeToken = json['typeToken'];
    token = json['token'];
    refreshToken = json['refreshToken'];
    contaContrato = json['contaContrato'];
    situacaoContrato = json['situacaoContrato'];
    planoContratado = json['planoContratado'];
    empresas = List.from(json['empresas']).map((e)=>Empresas.fromJson(e)).toList();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['authenticated'] = authenticated;
    _data['expiration'] = expiration;
    _data['message'] = message;
    _data['typeToken'] = typeToken;
    _data['token'] = token;
    _data['refreshToken'] = refreshToken;
    _data['contaContrato'] = contaContrato;
    _data['situacaoContrato'] = situacaoContrato;
    _data['planoContratado'] = planoContratado;
    _data['empresas'] = empresas.map((e)=>e.toJson()).toList();
    return _data;
  }
}

class Empresas {
  Empresas({
    required this.contaEmpresa,
    required this.selecionada,
    required this.razaoSocial,
    required this.fantasia,
    required this.identificador,
    required this.cpfcnpj,
    required this.apiToken,
  });
  late final int contaEmpresa;
  late final int selecionada;
  late final String razaoSocial;
  late final String fantasia;
  late final String identificador;
  late final String cpfcnpj;
  late final String apiToken;
  
  Empresas.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    contaEmpresa = json['contaEmpresa'];
    selecionada = json['selecionada'];
    razaoSocial = json['razaoSocial'];
    fantasia = json['fantasia'];
    identificador = json['identificador'];
    cpfcnpj = json['cpfcnpj'];
    apiToken = json['apiToken'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final _data = <String, dynamic>{};
    _data['contaEmpresa'] = contaEmpresa;
    _data['selecionada'] = selecionada;
    _data['razaoSocial'] = razaoSocial;
    _data['fantasia'] = fantasia;
    _data['identificador'] = identificador;
    _data['cpfcnpj'] = cpfcnpj;
    _data['apiToken'] = apiToken;
    return _data;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`json['empresas']` apparently returns a value of type `dynamic`.

I assume you just used `final json = jsonDecode(input);`

Here, `jsonDecode` has a return type of `dynamic`. So Flutter lets you call `['empresas']` on that object which may or may not exist.

Now, `List.from` requires the parameter to be of type `Iterable`, which `dynamic` is not. Therefore, an error is thrown.

As you know that the result of `json['empresas']` is a List, you could simply cast it:

```dart
final empresas = (json['empresas'] as List).map((e) => Empresas.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

or even better (because you know the structure of the json):

```dart
final empresas = (json['empresas'] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>)
    .map<Empresas>((e) => Empresas.fromJson(e))
    .toList();
```

(I added the `<Empresas>` type to the `map` function, so the return type is `List<Empresas>` instead of `List<dynamic>`)

Comment: Tks!!! it worked out!!!!

Comment: Awesome! I would appreciate it if you could accept this answer as solving your problem by clicking the check mark next to it :) @angelo-stevanelli